# Find the exact position of a drop inside a text node

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to find the exact position of a native (file) drop in HTML5?

I know, the *element* the user dropped the file on is provided by the event parameter, but I want to know exactly after which letter in the element's text the user dropped the item on.

Use case: I'm writing a little CMS and I want the user to be able to drop an image inside a `contenteditable` area and have it appear at the exact location they dropped it.

Comment: Doesn't the browser do that for you automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The drag event is of type [MouseEvent](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#the-dragevent-interface).  You should be able to get the `clientX` and `clientY` properties from the [`event` object](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#webidl-events-MouseEvent).

Comment: But that doesn't tell me the position inside the *text*, does it? Like document.getSelection()

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim If that part is what your problem really is then it's not specific to drag and drop (or HTML5), it's a general problem involving MouseEvents.  Maybe if you update your question title and your tags you'll get more eyes on this.